# Apache CXF jax-rs with Spring Boot: how to configure interceptors automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf

I have CXF Rest Api with using Spring Boot, so here's my application.properties:

```
cxf.path=/
cxf.jaxrs.server.address=/api
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true
cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan-packages=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger,org.apache.cxf.metrics
```

My endpoints are annotated as `@Component`, but the problem is I have not only the components or providers, but also ExceptionMappers, In/Out/Fault Interceptors.

Now I'm wondering if it can be configured via properties file as well.

And I know possible solution (don't propose me this one):

```
@Bean
public Server rsServer() {
  final JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();

  endpoint.setInInterceptors(Arrays.<Interceptor<? extends Message>>asList(
    interceptor1,
    interceptor2,
    interceptor3
  ));

  endpoint.setOutInterceptors(Arrays.<Interceptor<? extends Message>>asList(out1));
  endpoint.setOutFaultInterceptors(Arrays.<Interceptor<? extends Message>>asList(out1));

  endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.asList(
    provider1(),
    provider2()
  ));

  endpoint.setBus(bus);

  endpoint.setAddress("/api");

  endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.asList(
    endpoint1,
    endpoint2,
    ...,
    endpointN
  ));

  endpoint.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new Swagger2Feature()));
  return endpoint.create();
}
```

This is not cool at all as far as so many features can be configured automatically and now for some additional configs I have to configure everything manually.

It kills the purpose of using Spring Boot at all. So.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check [CxfAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/integration/spring-boot/autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/spring/boot/autoconfigure/CxfAutoConfiguration.java) and [AbstractSpringComponentScanServer.java](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/spring/AbstractSpringComponentScanServer.java), you need not create server bean manually, AutoConfiguration does for you, you need to just set property `cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true`, it will add all spring beans annotated `@Path` and `@Provider` to server instance. If you have custom interceptors make it bean by adding `@Component` and `@Provider(//with type)`. For Swagger and Metrics generally I create bean using `@Bean`, please check the example [here](https://github.com/kprasad99/cxf-swagger-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kp/swasthik/CxfConfig.java)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @karthik-prasadkart is correct. If you need even more flexibility you can also put this to `false`:

```
cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=false
```

And make an `@Configuration` class that extends `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.SpringComponentScanServer` (as that would normally be imported by the `cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true`). Here you can override methods and do last minute specific changes, for example in the `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.AbstractSpringConfigurationFactory#finalizeFactorySetup` method which is specifically meant for this.

```
@Configuration
public class CxfServerConfig extends SpringComponentScanServer {

    @Override
    protected void finalizeFactorySetup(JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory) {
        super.finalizeFactorySetup(factory);

        // Don't bypasses our exception mappers
        factory.getProperties(true).put("support.wae.spec.optimization", false);
    }
}
```